# Refresh Token is an Empty String

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am initializing a Firebase Auth instance in Flutter:

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

Then calling `.signInWithEmailAndPassword` method:

```
UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _newInputEmail, password: _newInputPassword);
```

What I am noticing is that the `refreshToken` property returns an empty string here:

```
                      var currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
                      if (currentUser != null) {
                        String token = await currentUser.getIdToken();
                        print("token: $token");
                        print("refresh token: ${currentUser.refreshToken}");
                      }
```

All other properties (e.g. String `token` from calling `await .getIdToken()`) do return data.

I was wondering if having a null string for `refreshToken` is expected when authenticating users in Flutter which in that case would mean that each user session lasts up to an hour?

Comment: Try adding `currentUser.reload()` before calling for the token

Comment: thank you @OreofeSolarin - that is an interesting thought. Unfortunately, empty string is still returned even after calling .reload() method.